# blindly classifying new trends in incoming data

Tags: statistics, artificial-intelligence, classification, bayesian

how do news outlets like google news automatically classify and rank documents about emerging topics, like "obama's 2011 budget"?

i've got a pile of articles tagged with baseball data like player names and relevance to the article (thanks, opencalais), and would love to create a google news-style interface that ranks and displays new posts as they come in, especially emerging topics. i suppose that a naive bayes classifier could be trained w/ some static categories, but this doesn't really allow for tracking trends like "this player was just traded to this team, these other players were also involved."

Comment: whoops, my fault. its gone now. thx.

Comment: Do you mean how it can generalize to unseen topics?

Answer (score 4):

No doubt, *Google News* may use other tricks (or even a combination thereof), but one relatively cheap trick, computationally, to infer topics from free-text would exploit the NLP notion that **a word gets its meaning only when connected to other words**.
An algorithm susceptible of discovering new topic categories from multiple documents could be outlined as follow:

- POS (part-of-speech) tag the text
  We probably want to focus more on nouns and maybe even more so on named entities (such as *Obama* or *New England*)
- Normalize the text
  In particular replace inflected words by their common stem.  Maybe even replace some adjectives by a corresponding Named Entity (ex:  Parisian ==> Paris,  legal ==> law)
  Also, remove noise words and noise expressions.
- identify some words from a list of manually maintained "current / recurring hot words"  (Superbowl, Elections, scandal...)
  This can be used in subsequent steps to provide more weight to some N-grams
- Enumerate all N-grams found in each documents (where N is 1 to say 4 or 5)
  Be sure to count, separately, the number of occurrences of each N-gram within a given document and the number of documents which cite a given N-gram
- The most frequently cited N-grams (i.e. the ones cited in the most documents) are probably the Topics.
- Identify the existing topics (from a list of known topics)
- [optionally] Manually review the new topics

This general recipe can also be altered to leverage other attributes of the documents and the text therein.  For example the document origin (say cnn/sports vs. cnn/politics ...) can be used to select domain specific lexicons.  Another example the process can more or less heavily emphasize the words/expressions from the document title (or other areas of the text with a particular mark-up).

Answer (score 2):

The main algorithms behind Google News have been published in the academic literature by Google researchers:

- [Original paper](http://www2007.org/papers/paper570.pdf).
- Talk: [Google News Personalization: Scalable Online Collaborative Filtering](http://videolectures.net/google_datar_gnp/)
- [Blog discussion](http://glinden.blogspot.com/2007/05/google-news-personalization-paper.html).